# ImportError: DLL Load failed (PyCrypto-2.6.1)

Tags: python

I'm using PyInstaller to convert the python file with the included modules to one Executable file with the following command:
`pyinstaller --onedir --onefile --name=IFSCP "C:\Python27\main.py"`
*I'm not using prefix --windowed, because the Python Program is in console mode.*

Everything went fine with compiling, but there is one issue while opening the executable. The following error comes up by loading the executable:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "main.py", line 13 in <module>
 File "C:\Users\Youri Kool\Desktop\pyinstaller-pyinstaller-8689a5d\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
     exec(bytecode, module, __dict__)
 File "c:\users\yourik~1\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-gzievh\pycrypto-2.6.1-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py", line 50, in <module>
 File "C:\Users\Youri Kool\Desktop\pyinstaller-pyinstaller-8689a5d\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
     exec(bytecode, module, __dict__)
 File "c:\users\yourik~1\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-gzievh\\pycrypto-2.6.1-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\Crypto\Cipher\_AES.py", line 7 in <module>
 File "c:\users\yourik~1\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-gzievh\\pycrypto-2.6.1-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\Crypto\Cipher\_AES.py", line 6 in __bootstrap__
```

ImportError: DLL load failed: Kan opgegeven module niet vinden.

*Kan opgegeven module niet vinden. -> Can't find module*

The ImportError don't show up without the
`from Crypto.Cipher import AES`
in the script.

Debug info:

```
C:\Users\Youri Kool\Desktop\pyinstaller-pyinstaller-8689a5d\IFSCP\dist>IFSCP.exe

PyInstaller Bootloader 3.x
LOADER: executable is C:\Users\Youri Kool\Desktop\pyinstaller-pyinstaller-8689a5
d\IFSCP\dist\IFSCP.exe
LOADER: homepath is C:\Users\Youri Kool\Desktop\pyinstaller-pyinstaller-8689a5d\
IFSCP\dist
LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is NULL
LOADER: archivename is C:\Users\Youri Kool\Desktop\pyinstaller-pyinstaller-8689a
5d\IFSCP\dist\IFSCP.exe
LOADER: Extracting binaries
LOADER: Executing self as child
LOADER: set _MEIPASS2 to C:\Users\YOURIK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI60522
LOADER: Setting up to run child
LOADER: Creating child process
LOADER: Waiting for child process to finish...
PyInstaller Bootloader 3.x
LOADER: executable is C:\Users\Youri Kool\Desktop\pyinstaller-pyinstaller-8689a5
d\IFSCP\dist\IFSCP.exe
LOADER: homepath is C:\Users\Youri Kool\Desktop\pyinstaller-pyinstaller-8689a5d\
IFSCP\dist
LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is C:\Users\YOURIK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI60522
LOADER: archivename is C:\Users\Youri Kool\Desktop\pyinstaller-pyinstaller-8689a
5d\IFSCP\dist\IFSCP.exe
LOADER: SetDllDirectory(C:\Users\YOURIK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI60522)
LOADER: Already in the child - running user's code.
LOADER: manifestpath: C:\Users\YOURIK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI60522\IFSCP.exe.m
anifest
LOADER: Activation context created
LOADER: Activation context activated
LOADER: Python library: C:\Users\YOURIK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI60522\python27.
dll
LOADER: Loaded functions from Python library.
LOADER: Manipulating environment (sys.path, sys.prefix)
LOADER: sys.prefix is C:\Users\YOURIK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI60~1
LOADER: Setting runtime options
LOADER: Bootloader option: pyi-windows-manifest-filename IFSCP.exe.manifest
LOADER: Initializing python
LOADER: Overriding Python's sys.path
LOADER: Post-init sys.path is C:\Users\YOURIK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI60522
LOADER: Setting sys.argv
LOADER: setting sys._MEIPASS
LOADER: importing modules from CArchive
LOADER: extracted struct
LOADER: callfunction returned...
LOADER: extracted pyimod01_os_path
LOADER: callfunction returned...
LOADER: extracted pyimod02_archive
LOADER: callfunction returned...
LOADER: extracted pyimod03_importers
LOADER: callfunction returned...
LOADER: Installing PYZ archive with Python modules.
LOADER: PYZ archive: out00-PYZ.pyz
LOADER: Running pyiboot01_bootstrap.py
LOADER: Running pyi_rth_pkgres.py
LOADER: Running pyi_rth__tkinter.py
LOADER: Running main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Youri Kool\Desktop\pyinstaller-pyinstaller-8689a5d\PyInstaller\
loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "c:\users\yourik~1\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-gzievh\pycrypto-2.6.1-
py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\Crypto\Cipher\_AES.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\yourik~1\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-gzievh\pycrypto-2.6.1-
py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\Crypto\Cipher\_AES.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: DLL load failed: Kan opgegeven module niet vinden.
Failed to execute script main
LOADER: OK.
LOADER: Cleaning up Python interpreter.
LOADER: Back to parent (RC: -1)
LOADER: Doing cleanup
LOADER: Freeing archive status for C:\Users\Youri Kool\Desktop\pyinstaller-pyins
taller-8689a5d\IFSCP\dist\IFSCP.exe
```

I installed the following applications:

- Pywin32 version 220
- cx-Freeze version 4.3.4
- PyCrypto version 2.6.1

Pyinstaller pyinstaller-pyinstaller-8689a5d (Developer) and PyInstaller-3.2 giving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `from Crypto.Cipher import AES` with `import Crypto`. Then in the code:

```
something = Crypto.Cipher.AES.new(...)
```

And my .exe worked fine